# logging system kill signals for debugging

Tags: python, linux, docker, logging, kill

I have a script run by python3.7.9 on my ubuntu18.04 docker container.

At some point the python interpreter is killed. This is likely caused by resource excess.

Using `docker log ${container_id}` I only get the stderr inside the container, but I am also interested in what kind of resource was exceeded, so that I can give useful feedback to development.

Is this automatically logged on a system level (linux, docker)?
If this is not the case, how can I log this?